# How to access odd and even objects in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have a NSArray where I would like to access the odd and even objects on an NSArray as they hold different values from one another.

effectivly this is all I am doing at the moment

```
- (void)splitArray:(NSArray)array {
   for (id object in array) { // this itterates my array
      // do stuff in here
   }
}
```

I need to figure out how to catch the objects that are even or odd... I was thinking something like

```
- (void)splitArray:(NSArray)array {
   int i = 1;
   for (id object in array) { // this itterates my array
      if (i == even) {
        // do stuff here
      }
      else if (i == odd) {
       // do stuff here
      }
     i++
   }
}
```

its just that I dont know what to use between the `if ()`

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Initialize your counter to zero, increment it at the end of the loop, and fizzbuzz out the rest.  Simple

Comment: wopps missed the increment.. will add now, in regards to starting at zero I know thats the way to do it if you looking to access specific elements of the array being that arrays start at 0.. but if I am looking to access odd/even would it not serve me better to initalise from 1?

Comment: 0 is even, I don't see a problem.  By initializing it to 1, you will skip the first element.

Comment: or you can use i variable like flag and if its 1 change it to 0 and if its 0 changed it to 1

Comment: right.. I see so how do I tell when **i** is odd or even for the if statments?

Comment: Use the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).  `i%2==0` is even

Comment: cool thank you :) will go from here..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To determine if an integer is even or odd, use the modulo `%` operator. If `index % 2 == 0` then it's even, else it's odd.

You can use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` to loop over your array without having to maintain the index separately.

```
- (void)splitArray:(NSArray *)array {
    [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        if (index % 2 == 0) {
            // even stuff here
        } else {
            // odd stuff here
        }
     }];
}
```

Comment: Instead of the modulo operator you can also do a bitwise & with 1, all positive odd numbers have their first bit set, bitwise & is often quicker than %. For negative number in practice the first bit will be set for odd numbers but, there are some exotic architectures where that is not the case.

Comment: I'm sure you could, but why?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, either set `i` to zero and increment it in the `for` loop or just use a normal `for` loop with the new NSArray syntax (assuming you're using a recent version of Xcode). Note also that you should be passing an `NSArray *`, not an `NSArray`:

```
- (void)splitArray:(NSArray*)array {
    for ( int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++ )
    {
        id object = array[i];

        if ( i % 2 == 0 ) {
            // even stuff here
        }
        else {
            //  odd stuff here
        }
    }
}
```